# how to close left side menu from code in a intel xdk hybrid app using appframework 3

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk, appframework

after navigate to a subpage i would like to close the left menu, but the app throw the "uib_sb is not defined".
how do i close the menu?

this the code to navigate:

```
$(document).on("click", ".uib_w_5", function(evt)
{
  activate_subpage("#page_83_54"); 
  uib_sb.close_all_sidebars();
});
```

this is the menu:

```
<nav class="af-sidemenu outer-element uib_w_2" data-side="left" id="uib_w_2" data-uib="app_framework/side_menu_area" data-ver="2">
                <div class="view active">
                    <header class="container-group outer-element uib_w_3" data-uib="app_framework/header" data-ver="3" id="af-header-1">
                        <h1>Prova</h1>
                        <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
                        <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col header-left"></div>
                        <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col header-right"></div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="pages">
                        <div class="panel active">
                            <div class="col uib_col_1 single-col" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                                <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                    <ul class="list widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/listview" data-ver="2">
                                        <li class="widget uib_w_5" data-uib="app_framework/listitem" data-ver="2"><a>ricerca per produttore</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="widget uib_w_6" data-uib="app_framework/listitem" data-ver="2"><a>ricerca per scheda</a>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this:

```
$.afui.drawer.hide ("#uib_w_2", "left");
```